# Json jquery Ie8 issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I try to understand where is my mistake, and I cannot find it: this is my code

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('ajax/data.json', function(data) {
             $.each(data.results, function(i,item){
                    alert(item.foo);
                });
        });
    });
```

and data.json file:

```
{
    "results":[
        {
          "foo": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
          "bar": "ABCDEFG",
          "baz": [52, 97]
        },
        {
          "foo": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
          "bar": "ABCDEFG",
          "baz": [52, 97]
        },
    ]
}
```

Works fine in IE7, FF, but doesn't work in IE8

Can you help me, what's wrong here?

PS: using 1.4.3 jquery version

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid JSON, a trailing comma:

```
    },
```

This is illegal JSON, tolerated by all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the alert javascript function for debugging, which is a blocking call. It changes the behavior of the javascript. For debugging purposes use jQuery to add the item to a ul or debug using firebug.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('ajax/data.json', function(data) {
         $.each(data.results, function(i,item){
                $('<li>').text(item.foo).appendTo('#results');
            });
    });
});

<body>
<ul id="results">
</ul>
</body>
```

Using this approach worked for me in FF and IE8.